# How to use negative globbing properly to clean up unnecessary files from artifact?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline that seems to be working as intended so far.
However, one thing bothering me and the devs is that the resulting artifact has lots of unnecessary files that get deployed when consumed by the release pipeline, and whilst it doesn't harm the web app, it adds all those unnecessary dependency (i.e. dll) and debug (e.g. pdb) files that serve no purpose.

Here is the expected artifact:

[image: expected]

Here is the one being produced today:

[image: prod]

Here is what's inside the zip file:

[image: zip content]

The zip file needs to look like the expected artifact as well. In fact if I can just produce the zip file with content inside looking exactly like the expected artifact above, that would be fantastic.

**Note** that I trimmed most of the pdb/dll/xml files out of the pictures because the list is too long, but I hope you get the idea.

Here are the copy task and relevant task YAMLs:

```
steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/_PublishedWebsites/Project123'
    Contents: |
     assets/**
     bin/**
     Content/**
     Scripts/**
     Views/**
     *.config
     *.asax
     *.ico
     *.txt
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  
steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: Project123
    Contents: |
     Bundles/**
     !(packages.config|phantomjs-license.txt)
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

steps:
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    verbose: true
    
steps:
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: Release'
  inputs:
    ArtifactName: Release
```

I've tried different combos of negative globbing but I can't seem to get it right to remove the unnecessary files to achieve one like the expected artifact.

I don't want to use Powershell task, I want to use negative globbing in the copy tasks if possible to remove these files.

Comment: What did you try? basically you can do `!*.dll` and `!*.pdb` in it will exclude them in the copy task.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk nope that didnt work, unfortunately. However, check out the solution! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the solution by mere coincidence after so many trial/error!!!

The idea is basically setting the copy task ***TargetFolder*** attribute to not only the root ***Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory***, but to a ***subfolder (e.g. Release or Drop)*** that is published eventually, like so:

```
TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Release'
```

Ensure the archive file path is also updated to that subfolder location:

```
archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Release/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

and finally, ensure the publish artifact ***PathtoPublish*** attribute is also adjusted to the subfolder:

```
PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Release'
ArtifactName: Release
```

I also ended up rearranging the copy tasks, I figured it’d make more sense to copy the ***Bundles*** directory containing the ***AngularOutput*** to the ***_PublishedWebsites***, and this way ***_PublishedWebsites*** will serve as the source directory for ALL the artifact contents we want to archive/publish

Hence, here’s the updated and working copy/archive/publish YAML!

```
steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/_PublishedWebsites/Project123'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: Project123
    Contents: |
     Bundles/**
     !(packages.config|phantomjs-license.txt)
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/_PublishedWebsites/Project123'
    
steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Release'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/_PublishedWebsites/Project123'
    Contents: |
     assets/**
     bin/**
     Bundles/**
     Content/**
     Scripts/**
     Views/**
     Web.config
     ApplicationInsights.config
     *.asax
     *.ico
     *.txt
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Release'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  
steps:
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Release'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Release'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Release/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    verbose: true

steps:
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: Release'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Release'
    ArtifactName: Release
```

Resulting Release

[image: release]